# Getting Google Maps release api key

Tags: android

I have published an app on Google Play but map is blank and I cannot figure out how to find the resulting api key that I need and where to put it. I have my SHA1 fingerprint and my api key that is for debugging.

Works great on my device but not after publishing. Every video and post I see on this is from years ago and doesn't seem to work. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Google play console where select the app and in left side : Release management=> App Signing=> copy SHA-1 certificate inside App signing certificatemodule and paste into the Google cloud console and add this SHA1 with your project and save it . it will work . it works me.

Comment: how do i add it to project

Comment: figured it out and thank you for your help it worked